# How to overwrite information correctly and how to add a new one if there is no PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Faced with such a situation. I need to count the number of rows for matching and write them down. Here is my sql query:

```
INSERT INTO result(source, object, redirect, model, quantity)
SELECT source, object, redirect, model, count(*)
FROM machines_in_operation
GROUP BY source, object, redirect, model
ORDER BY redirect;
```

But the problem is that I don't understand how to write a condition, then if the information changed, then he would overwrite and not add a new record. And a new record needs to be added if there is no such client, the redirect column is responsible for this. The quantity and the object (object and quantity) will change

I understood what UPDATE is needed, but I don't know how to apply it correctly.

Comment: It sounds like maybe the `result` table should not even exist.  Instead, just create a view which contains your aggregation query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is needed because the data will still be filled in it, but they will be different.

Comment: @JNevill The first time I hear, I'm going to read

Comment: you are looking for `insert ... on conflict do update ...`

Comment: I don't understand what's going on here

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh shoot. Completely whiffed on that one. Jon/OP: essentially the functionality you are after is traditionally called "UPSERT". Each RDBMS implements this functionality differently. I incorrectly assumed Postgres implemented this feature as `MERGE`, but I was mistaken. As Horse said `insert ... on conflict do update ...` is the upsert implementation in postgres that you want to use. I will remove my previous comment.

Comment: Also, Jon/OP, Tim is suggesting that you don't even need a separate table to track "results" and instead should consider just running this same SELECt statement whenever you need to get this data. You can toss that SELECT into a view and select form that instead. Which direction you go (both are valid and used often depending on requirements) is up to you.

Comment: @JNevill instead of INSERT INTO, it will put UPSERT?

Comment: "UPSERT" is the generic term folks generally use. It means "Update records in the target table when the source table has a record with the same key. If there is no match on key, then Insert a new record into the target table". It's a portmanteau of UPdate and inSERT. Each RDBMS enables this feature differently. Some have a "MERGE" statement and others, like Postgres, use a regular INSERT statement with the extra "ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE" clause. [Here's a good overview of the feature](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/postgresql/inserting-and-modifying-data/insert-on-conflict).

Comment: How would you determine that there is already a matching entry in `result`?